How to prevent Angular form control from showing validation errors (red outline) on load in a reusable input component?
I’m working on an Angular form with a custom reusable input component that has required fields using Validators.required. When the page loads, the form controls are initially empty and marked as invalid, which causes a red outline (from the is-invalid class) to be applied to the input fields immediately.
The issue:
Even though the form is invalid on load (which is expected), I don’t want the validation error styles (like the red outline) to show immediately. Instead, I want to display the validation errors only after the user interacts with the input fields (i.e., after the field is touched or dirty).
I am using a custom reusable input component (cx-input-text) for handling form controls in a generic way. The cx-input-text component uses ControlValueAccessor to interact with Angular's reactive forms.
Login HTML:
<form [formGroup]="loginForm" class="formclass" (ngSubmit)="loginUser()">
      <div class="contan align-items-center justify-content-center">
        <cx-input-text
          inputId="id"
          formControlName="id"
          placeholder="id Number"
          inputClass="'inputText'"
          label="Id"
        ></cx-input-text>

        <cx-input-text
          inputId="email"
          formControlName="email"
          placeholder="email@email.com"
          inputClass="'inputText'"
          label="Email"
        ></cx-input-text>

        <cx-password
          id="password"
          formControlName="password"
          labelText="Enter Password"
          passwordClass="passwordText"
          passwordLabel="Password"
          passwordAnchor="Forget Password"
          autocomplete="off"
          [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': loginForm.controls['businessid'].touched && loginForm.controls['businessid'].invalid }"
        ></cx-password>

        <div class="form-group">
          <cx-checkbox labelText="Remember me"> </cx-checkbox>
        </div>
        <cx-button [disabled]="loginForm.invalid" labelText="Sign In" (buttonClick)="loginUser()"></cx-button>
        <ng-container *ngIf="isLoading$ | async">
          <span class="spinner spinner-primary ml-5"></span>
        </ng-container>
      </div>
    </form>

LoginComponent Form Initialization:
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.loginForm = this.fb.group({
    id: ['', Validators.required],
    email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
    password: ['', Validators.required]
  });

  // Mark all controls as pristine and untouched on load
  this.loginForm.markAsPristine();
  this.loginForm.markAsUntouched();
}


cx-input-text (Custom Reusable Input Component):
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="label-class my-2">
    <label for="username">{{ label }}</label>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="control">
    <input
      [required]="isRequired"
      [type]="type"
      [id]="inputId"
      pInputText
      [formControl]="control"
      [placeholder]="placeholder"
      [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': control.invalid && (control.touched || control.dirty) }"
    />
    <!-- Only show error messages if control is touched or dirty -->
    <div *ngIf="control.invalid && (control.touched || control.dirty)">
      <cx-validation-errors [customErrorMessages]="customErrorMessages" [errors]="control.errors"></cx-validation-errors>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


ControlValueAccessor Directive (used in cx-input-text):
export class ControlValueAccessorDirective<T> implements ControlValueAccessor, OnInit {
  control: FormControl | undefined;
  isRequired = false;

  constructor(@Inject(Injector) private injector: Injector) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.setFormControl();
    this.isRequired = this.control?.hasValidator(Validators.required) ?? false;
    this.control?.markAsPristine();
    this.control?.markAsUntouched();
  }

  setFormControl(): void {
    const formControl = this.injector.get(NgControl);
    this.control = formControl.control as FormControl;
  }

  writeValue(value: string[]): void {
    if (this.control) {
      this.control.setValue(value[0], { emitEvent: false });
    }
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: (val: T | null) => T): void {
    this.control?.valueChanges.subscribe(fn);
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: () => T): void {}
}


The Problem:
Form controls are invalid on load due to the Validators.required.
I don't want to show the red outline (validation error) immediately on page load, but only after the user interacts with the input (i.e., when the control becomes touched or dirty).
What I've Tried:
Using markAsPristine() and markAsUntouched() in both the LoginComponent and ControlValueAccessorDirective to reset the form state on load.
Conditionally applying the is-invalid class based on control.invalid && (control.touched || control.dirty) to delay showing validation errors until the user interacts with the input.
Question:
How can I ensure that Angular form controls in a custom reusable input component (using ControlValueAccessor) do not show validation errors (like the red outline) immediately on load, but only after the user interacts with the input?
